Is $\frac{{dy}^2}{{dx}^2} = ({\frac{dy}{dx}})^2$?
Is $\frac{{dy}^2}{{dx}^2} = ({\frac{dy}{dx}})^2$?
Problem: If $x = t \cos(t)$ and $y = t + \sin(t)$ then find $\frac{d^2 x}{dy^2}$ at $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$.
My attempt: $\frac{d^2 x}{dy^2}=\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} \times \frac{dt^2}{dy^2}$.
$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$ is just the 2nd derivative of $x = t \cos(t)$. However can I say that $\frac{{dy}^2}{{dt}^2} = ({\frac{dy}{dt}})^2$ so that I can plug the first derivative of $y = t + \sin(t)$ into the equation to get the result?
What is the correct way to solve this question?

But isn't acceleration= $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$ and not $\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}$

Be careful with Leibniz notation. $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is 'really' $\frac{d^2ydx-d^2xdy}{dx^3}$ and so the manipulations you did do not hold in general. (Regarding your actual question, in general $\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}=(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$)

@Fishbane , but when I use $\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}=(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$ , it doesn't give the correct answer.

@rohit1729 As I said that is because the rest of your manipulations do not hold in general. You cannot manipulate Leibniz notation derivatives like fractions if they have order greater than 2. To do so you have to first correct the notation. The correct formula is more complicated.

My advice is, don't write ${dy^2\over dx^2}$. It is an abomination, no one ever writes it, it will only lead you to errors and confusion. It is not needed, it doesn't do anything for us. Just don't use it, and you'll be happy.

@GerryMyerson I disagree that $\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}$ is useless (for example proper use can easily give the correct formula for change of variables of a second derivative), but I would say that unless you are comfortable with using corrected Leibniz notation you will just confuse yourself and so anyone new to calculus should stay away.

@GerryMyerson , so I should keep all terms linear without multiplying them right ? Like what Afntu did?

$(dy)^2$ is the square or the derivate, $d^2y$ is the second derivate. Don't mix those up.

I'd say you should find ${dx\over dy}$ as ${dx\over dt}\div{dy\over dt}$, then get ${d^2y\over dx^2}$ by differentiating with respect to $y$, using ${dt\over dy}=1\div{dy\over dt}$.

@ClaudeLeibovici  If $x$ and $y$ are measured in meters and $t$ in seconds the claimed equality may hold. The LHS is not the acceleration and $dy/dx$ is not the speed. The are the ratios of changes of $x$ and $y.$

Read this and when to treat dy/dx as a fraction

$\frac{{dy}^2}{{dx}^2} = ({\frac{dy}{dx}})^2$ = the square of the first derivative.  $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is the second derivative.  They are NOT the same thing.

@Dan, I've never seen anyone use ${dy^2\over dx^2}$ as notation for the square of ${dy\over dx}$.

Observe that $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \dfrac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{dy}{dx}) = \dfrac{d}{dt}({\dfrac{dy}{dx}})\dfrac{dt}{dx} = \dfrac{\dfrac{d}{dt}(\dfrac{dy}{dx})}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$, where $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$.
Also observe that, $\dfrac{dy^2}{dx^2}=\dfrac{2ydy}{2xdx}= \dfrac{y}{x}\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. From this, your query is true iff $y=cx$, where $c$ is a constant.
Now choose $y=x^2$, then $\dfrac{dy^2}{dx^2} = 2x^2$ and $(\dfrac{dy}{dx})^2 = 4x^2$, hence $\dfrac{{dy}^2}{{dx}^2} \neq ({\dfrac{dy}{dx}})^2$, in general.

just a small doubt. how did u calculate $\frac{{dy}^2}{{dx}^2}$ of y=x

Sorry, my bad. Example should be $y = x^2$

Oh so you squared the function and then differentiated it w.r.t $x^2$. But is $dy^2$=$d(y^2)$ or is it $(dy)^2$. I think it's the second one?

I disagree with the very first thing you wrote, Afntu. You have written ${d^2y\over d^2x}$ where you ought to have written ${d^2y\over dx^2}$. OP is already confused enough about the notation, without someone compounding OP's errors.

The two things are different, and you must be careful about this when you are writing these things.

Sorry, @GerryMyerson, I made a mistake when I wrote it. Thanks for pointing out. I updated my answer.
